# What is the idiomatic way to reassign parameter bindings?

Tags: parameters, rust, idioms

Sometimes I reassign parameter bindings because the original binding is no longer needed and could lead to confusion. What is the idiomatic way to handle this? For example:

```
fn foo(s: &str) {
    let s = s.trim();
}
```

or

```
fn foo(mut s: &str) {
    s = s.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first solution is better. An immutable binding is always better than a mutable one when possible. That is why Rust's bindings are immutable by default and why you have to type an additional keyword to have a variable like in most procedural languages.

When you use mutable variable, you can accidentally change the value:

```
fn foo(mut i1: u32) {
    i1 = i1.count_ones();
    let mut i2 = 0_u32;

    // Some lines

    i1 = 42; // Oops, I wrote `i1` instead of `i2`
}
```

If you use the immutable version, this cannot happen:

```
fn foo(i1: u32) {
    let i1 = i1.count_ones();
    let mut i2 = 0_u32;

    // Some lines

    i1 = 42; // error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `i1`
}
```

You need to use a mutable variable only when you have to feed it to another scope for modification purpose:

```
fn main() {
    let mut to_be_modified = 123;

    {
        // do something in another scope
        to_be_modified = 456;
    }

    // in another function
    foo(&mut to_be_modified);
}

fn foo(i: &mut i32) {
    *i = 789;
}
```